# How to avoid the dummy variable trap when dummy coding several treatments plus control group for linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, dummy-variable

I understand that I need one dummy variable less than the total number of dummy variables. However, I am stuck, because I keep receiving the error: "1 not defined because of singularities", when running lm in R. I found a similar question here: [What is causing this error? Coefficients not defined because of singularities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989003/what-is-causing-this-error-coefficients-not-defined-because-of-singularities) but it is slightly different than my problem.

I have two treatments (1) "benefit" and (2) "history", with two Levels each (1) "low" and "high" and (2) "short" and "long", i.e. 4 combinations. Additionally, I have a Control Group, which was exposed to neither. Therefore, I coded 4 dummy variables (which is one less than the total number of Groups n=5). Followingly, the dummy coded data looks like this:

```
                               low benefit  high benefit  short history  long history
Control group                           0             o              0             0
low benefit, short history              1             0              1             0
low benefit, long history               1             0              0             1
high benefit, short history             0             1              1             0
high benefit, long history              0             1              0             1
```

When I run my lm I get this:

```
Model: 
summary(lm(X ~ short history + high benefit + long history + low benefit + Control variables, data = df))

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                                         Estimate   Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                           5.505398100  0.963932438  5.71139  4.8663e-08 ***
Dummy short history                   0.939025772  0.379091565  2.47704   0.0142196 *
Dummy high benefit                   -0.759944023  0.288192645 -2.63693   0.0091367 **
Dummy long history                    0.759352915  0.389085599  1.95163   0.0526152 .
Dummy low benefit                              NA           NA       NA          NA
Control Varibales                          xxx          xxx        xxx       xxx
```

This error occurs always for the dummy varibale at the 4th Position. The Control variables are all calculated without problem.

I already tried to only include two variables with two levels, meaning for "history" I coded, 1 for "long" and 0 for "short", and for "benefit", 1 for "high" and 0 for "low". This way, the lm worked, but the problem is, that the Control Group and the combination "short history, low benefit" are coded identically, i.e. 0 and 0 for both variables.

I am sorry, if this is a basic mistake but I have not been able to figure it out. If you need more information, please say so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only have **two** variables.  They are `benefit` and `history`  each of those variables has three levels (short, long, control) and (high, low, control).  Code the variables so that in each case `control` is the base level you are comparing to by contrasts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I put in the comments you only have two variables, if you make them factors and check the contrasts `r` will do the right thing.  Please also see http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/

Make up data representative of yours.

```r
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(
  X = runif(n = 120, min = 5, max = 15),
  benefit = rep(c("control", "low", "high"), 40),
  history = c(rep("control", 40), rep("long", 40), rep("short", 40))
)
```

Make `benefit` and `history` factors, check that control is the base contrast for each.

```r
df$benefit <- factor(df$benefit)
df$history <- factor(df$history)
contrasts(df$benefit)
#>         high low
#> control    0   0
#> high       1   0
#> low        0   1
contrasts(df$history)
#>         long short
#> control    0     0
#> long       1     0
#> short      0     1
```

Run the regression and get the summary.  4 coefficient all conpared to control/control.

```r
lm(X ~ benefit + history, df)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = X ~ benefit + history, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  (Intercept)   benefithigh    benefitlow   historylong  historyshort  
#>      9.94474      -0.08721       0.11245       0.37021      -0.35675
summary(lm(X ~ benefit + history, df))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = X ~ benefit + history, data = df)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -5.4059 -2.3706 -0.0007  2.4986  4.7669 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)   9.94474    0.56786  17.513   <2e-16 ***
#> benefithigh  -0.08721    0.62842  -0.139    0.890    
#> benefitlow    0.11245    0.62842   0.179    0.858    
#> historylong   0.37021    0.62842   0.589    0.557    
#> historyshort -0.35675    0.62842  -0.568    0.571    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.809 on 115 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.01253,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02182 
#> F-statistic: 0.3648 on 4 and 115 DF,  p-value: 0.8333
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I did exactly as you proposed and when running `contrasts` I receive the same output as you do. However, when running the regression with the two variables (á 3 Levels), I still receive the same error for the same position. I thought maybe it is because of the control variables, but even when I omit them, the error remains. Is it possible that the error occurs cause I have "only" 31-38 per level and the control group is split (while you had 40 each)?

Comment: Sorry I have to correct myself. My data looks as follows:

```> table(df$history)

 # Ctr  Long Short 
   35    76    70 
> table(df$Benefi)

# Ctr High  low 
  35   70   76 
```

Comment: Could you please append the error message you receive now?  Could you also please do a dput(head(df, 20)).  Is it possible that `history` and `benefit` are conflated, that is people tend to clump by level of the factor?  If they are highly related then the message is accurate.  What happens when you run each lm separately like `summary(lm(X ~ benefit, df))` and `summary(lm(X ~ history, df))`.  The fact that you don't have a perfectly balanced design in and of itself shouldn't matter.

Comment: The message is as follows: "Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)" which is followed by NA as describe above. When I run the lm seperatly, it works fine. Obviously, the variables within a treatment are highly correlated because when e.g. "short" is coded as 1, then "long" has to be 0. Strangely, a correlation test revealed that "short" and "low" as well as "long" and "high" are statsitically signficantly correlated (r = .22, p < .01), even though I randomized. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: `> dput(head(df, 25))
structure(list(X = c(3, 7, 1, 2.5, 5.5, 4, 
2, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1.5, 5.5, 6.5, 4, 6.5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3.5, 1, 4, 
2, 5), Benefit = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Ctr", "High", "low"), class = "factor"), 
    CSP = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L), .Label = c("Ctr", "Long", "Short"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Ugh sorry I should have seen this right away.  The problem is all your controls have no benefits and no CSP so when you do `table(df2$Benefit, df2$CSP)` there's 35 in the top left corner but the top row has 2 zeroes as does the left column that's what generates the singularity.  You can run the regression minus the CTR group and generate slopes and you can also generate means for all  5 conditions but those 4 empty cells won't allow you to generate a regression line.  Try `aggregate(X ~ CSP + Benefit, data = df, mean)`

Comment: I see, thank you so much for your help. I reckon there is no "trick" to code the dummies so that the singularity disappears without manipulating the results?

Comment: No, the means give you a way of comparing X across the various levels against `control` but there is no way to generate rates (slopes) that have control since it is totally confounded with condition.