# lm: 1 coefficient not defined because of singularities while no major collinearity issues

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have seen similar posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989062/16760971) which say that getting the error message saying: `Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)` is because of nearly perfect correlation among predictors used in the `lm()` call.

But in my case, there is no nearly perfect correlation among predictors, but still one coefficient (`X_wthn_outcome`) returns `NA` in the output of `lm()`.

I wonder what is wrong with the coefficient that returns `NA`?

For reproducibility purposes, the exact same data and code is provided below.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(132)
(data <- expand.grid(study = 1:1e3, outcome = rep(1:50,2)))
data$X <- rnorm(nrow(data))
e <- rnorm(nrow(data), 0, 2)
data$yi <- .8 +.6*data$X + e

dat <- data %>% 
  group_by(study) %>% 
  mutate(X_btw_study = mean(X), X_wthn_study = X-X_btw_study) %>%
  group_by(outcome, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(X_btw_outcome = mean(X), X_wthn_outcome = X-X_btw_outcome) %>% ungroup()
  
round(cor(select(dat,-study,-outcome,-X,-yi)),3)

#               X_btw_study X_wthn_study X_btw_outcome X_wthn_outcome
#X_btw_study          1.000        0.000         0.141           0.00
#X_wthn_study         0.000        1.000         0.698           0.71
#X_btw_outcome        0.141        0.698         1.000           0.00
#X_wthn_outcome       0.000        0.710         0.000           1.00

summary(lm(yi ~ 0 + X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study
   + X_wthn_outcome, data = dat))

#Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#X_btw_study    0.524093   0.069610   7.529 5.15e-14 ***
#X_btw_outcome  0.014557   0.013694   1.063    0.288    
#X_wthn_study   0.589517   0.009649  61.096  < 2e-16 ***
#X_wthn_outcome       NA         NA      NA       NA  ## What's wrong with this variable
```

Comment: You say there was "no nearly perfect correlation among predictors", but two-way collinearity is not the same as multi-collinearity. If you have a lot of categorical predictors (or a few categorical with small sample size) it's not that hard to get "perfect multicollinearity" without any two way correlations that look worrisome.

Comment: @IRTFM, I have no categorical predictors. But can you possibly show what you exactly mean by multi-collinearity in my data above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have constructed a problem where the three-way combination of `X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study` perfectly predicts `X_wthn_outcome`:

```
lm(X_wthn_outcome ~ X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study , data = dat)
#------------------
Call:
lm(formula = X_wthn_outcome ~ X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study, 
    data = dat)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)    X_btw_study  X_btw_outcome   X_wthn_study  
    1.165e-17      1.000e+00     -1.000e+00      1.000e+00  
#--------------
summary( lm(X_wthn_outcome ~ X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study , data = dat) )

#---------------
Call:
lm(formula = X_wthn_outcome ~ X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study, 
    data = dat)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-3.901e-14 -6.000e-17  0.000e+00  5.000e-17  3.195e-13 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    1.165e-17  3.242e-18  3.594e+00 0.000326 ***
X_btw_study    1.000e+00  3.312e-17  3.020e+16  < 2e-16 ***
X_btw_outcome -1.000e+00  6.515e-18 -1.535e+17  < 2e-16 ***
X_wthn_study   1.000e+00  4.590e-18  2.178e+17  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.025e-15 on 99996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 1.582e+34 on 3 and 99996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You have an adjusted R^2 of 1 with three predictors. So MULTI-collinearity but not two-way collinearity. (R has caught on to your tricks and won't let you get away with this `dplyr` game of "hide the dependencies".) I think the dependencies might have been more apparently if you had build the variables in a sequence of separate steps rather than in a piped chain.

Comment: Aha! +1. But why so? Why `X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study` fully predict/overlap with `X_wthn_outcome`?

Comment: Because of your sequence of steps in building those variables. You really only had three independent variables, Y, e and X, and everything else was built from them using means and differences.

Comment: Sure, but I thought I broke `X` into four non-overlapping parts.

Comment: So? That didn't remove the row-wise dependencies. Every single rows had that problem.

Comment: row-wise dependencies?

Comment: Every single row had X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study  == X_wthn_outcome. I don't read `dplyr` chains very well so I couldn't see it in your code but I think that you tricked yourself by not making separate lines for your variable creation.

Comment: But if I do: `with(dat, X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study)` I don't get `X_wthn_outcome`?

Comment: OK I guess my assertion wan't correct, but the R^2 for those three variables X_btw_study + X_btw_outcome + X_wthn_study()  predicting   X_wthn_outcome os still 1.000 so there is a nearly  perfect joint dependency. And as I said I have a lot of trouble reading `dplyr` code, so I can't tell exactly what you did. (And it appears you can't either.)

Comment: Here is what I did: For rows within each study, I took mean of `X`. Subtracted that mean from `X` values within each study. For rows within each study, I took the mean of `X` values for rows with the same outcome value. Subtracted those means from their respective `X` value. If that is confusing let me know.

Comment: You have ended up with two variable with a sum of zero and two with the same sum:  `with( dat, sum(  X_wthn_outcome))
[1] 2.834885e-14

> with( dat, sum(  X_wthn_study))
[1] -4.184847e-14
> with( dat, sum(  X_btw_outcome))
[1] -12.19032
> with( dat, sum(  X_btw_study))
[1] -12.19032`

Comment: Hummm! So essentially `X_btw_outcome == X_btw_study`, and on the other hand `X_wthn_outcome == X_wthn_study`.  Which also mean to recreate the original `X` only following is enough `within(dat, X_recreated <- X_wthn_outcome + X_btw_outcome)` or `within(dat, X_recreated <- X_wthn_study + X_btw_study)` is enough.